# Need to copy an entire table from SQL Server to SQL Server CE including the table structure and all data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm looking to copy tables including all their data from SQL Server to a SQL CE database in C# on demand.
The trick is, the tables being copied will not be known until runtime and will not previously exist in the SQL CE database.

I'm hoping to do this by getting a DataTable from the server first and then copying that into the CE database.

What is the simplest way to insert that new table and its data to the SQL Server CE database?

And is there an alternative method I should consider?

The method would have to work on any version of SQL Server from 2005 and up so I cannot rely on a feature only available in newer versions.

The local DB will always be blank.

The tables may contain up to several thousand records and this is going to be used as a local cache.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. Maybe you should look into Talend https://www.talend.com. Its an open software for data integration. Using this tool i successfully copied some tables from Microsoft Server to MySQL server. Besides that it allows you to make jobs, which you can export for different OS to run them.

Comment: I'd prefer to not use a 3rd party solution to do this, especially if it's not a free one.

Comment: Read again. It is free. And its the best software out there for such problems (transfering from one database type, to another.

Comment: @MiKE There are certain data constraints from a business standpoint that you cannot use third party software. These may be of concern to OP.  For example, Healthcare data. You only addressed one concern, the other might be more important. Keep in mind, with paid software you can usually get BAA. Third party software you never know what you're exposing or to whom.

Comment: @Hituptony I help based on the information OP gives us. I cannot adapt my solution on a pure "assumption" what he 'may' be doing. In OP's comment he said he rather not use a 3rd party solution that is not free. Well, Talend is free and is far from 3rd party. Its a well known and professional software. He asked for an alternative to consider, this is one in my opinion. And his condition to work on all databases from 2005 is also met. If security is really an issue i doubt a code snippet from here would be a proper way in the first place. This is all i have to say. Kind regards!

Comment: Performance and ease of use are the more important factors.  It is something that would need to be included in each install of the application to each of our customers.  My mistake on the pricing of the suggested solution.  I browsed the site for just a bit and that was the impression from the way things were worded especially when it said "free trial"  I will take another look at that.  If I know I'm sticking with SQL Server 2005+ and SQLCE, is my original suggestion not practical?

Comment: Ok I did find the open source version you mentioned. I just had to get past the paid ones that were promoted above them.  The download is very large. I'm guessing that in order for me to use this, I'd need the full install on the machine I'm running my  application from?  If so, that will not work for me sadly.  It has to be portable, not require an install as I have no control over which machine my application will run on, my only assumption is that the machine has .NEt installed and access to the SQL server already.

Comment: I understand. I'm sorry then, i cannot help you further, because i do not have time to write an example. I suggest you search a little more on the internet. There are plenty of solution how to connect to a SQL server using a connectiong string and further geting the data info. I think you can connect all the snippets and create a good portable app for your problem!

Answer (score 0):

What I've done so far and tested on a sample project is:

- Get the data into a `DataTable` from SQL Server
- Create a create table script using the `DataTable`'s column collection
- Run that against my SQL Server CE database

And found a library written by someone else to do a bulk copy into the CE database since the regular SQL bulk copy does not support CE.

I need to integrate it into the main app and test it against real production data to see how it performs, but provided that is acceptable I'm going this route I think.